# Is there a way to change videos resolution when recording with xamarin community tool kit's camera view?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.communitytoolkit

With the default settings, The video size is too large with 1920x1080 resolution making it hard to upload to a server. I want to keep the same audio and video codecs, but lower the resolution.

Xamarin community tool kit doesn't seem to offer anyway to change it

Comment: There is no a such api can set the resolution before you record the video.

Comment: What about after?

Comment: So you can try to change the vedio's resolution after the recording completed instead of before recording.